Changed name tag on doorbell - is this a known scam?
A friend of mine just told me that her packages could not be delivered because it seemed she did not reside at the address. After investigation, she found that someone glued another name tag over her name tag on her doorbell. The new name tag has the same name as the person that lived there before and has scratch marks as if someone failed to remove it, but it is still clearly readable. She already lives in this flat for years now.
I'm wondering if this is a new sophisticated post scam attempt.
Clarifications (specific situation in Germany):

Her original name tag was in the doorbell, the new one was printed out with a label printer and stuck on top. Her name tag was therefore still under the new tag.
This is an apartment complex with at least 10 tenants in a large city. It is not usual for mail carriers to ask if a name is not at the address on the parcel.
If the recipient is not at home, the driver usually puts a note in the letterbox and drops the parcel off at the nearest post office. If the recipient cannot be identified, it is customary to return the parcel to the sender.


I’m voting to close this question because it is not about personal finance. Seems like a physical security question.

This sounds more like her name tag fell off, exposing the previous one, than like somebody applied a new one. And I agree, it is out of scope; not all scams are on topic here.

This seems like a spurious excuse. There are plenty of reasons why the name of the recipient wouldn't be on the doorbell, starting with living with a person who has a different last name. If your friend really had this happen, your friend should just get the deliverer to deliver the package whatever is on the doorbell.

@keshlam her name Tag was present beneath the new one as it is inside the doorbell case and the new one was stuck on top of the doorbell.

Sorry, I thought scam belongs here. Which is the right stack exchange?

@ i should have clarified, it is an apartment building with at least 10 residents. If you are at someone else's place you would put the name as c/o on the package, at least where she lives (Germany)

This is a personal finance discussion, which means we often get into the topic of financial scams, but it isn't clear that this falls in that set. I'm not sure where a better place would be; it might not be on Stack Exchange. Some governments maintain lists of things to watch out for; it might be worth reading some of those pages to see if they mention this particular problem.

I agree with @DJClayworth that the delivery service should be delivering to that person at that address, and if that name isn't on the mailbox they should knock and ask for that person. Some parcel services fail to do so even when you have paid for hand to hand delivery with signature, and since parcel services these days often transship on other services one bad actor can break things for everyone.

I stumbled upon the following description of a scam:

The scam begins when fraudsters create accounts on popular platforms such as
Amazon or Zalando using someone else's address. Using the “pay later”
option, they order goods without prepayment.
Once the package is on its way, the scammers track the delivery via
tracking notifications. They intercept the delivery person at the
victim's front door and claim that the parcel is for them.
Unsuspectingly, the delivery person hands it over and the fraudster
disappears - leaving the victim stuck with the bill.
The combination of real-time tracking and the ability to meet delivery
drivers in person makes this scam alarmingly effective. Delivery
drivers often have no means of verifying identities, which facilitates
these scams.

However, there is no mention of the name tags being changed. I could imagine that someone had the victim's old address and had to find a workaround and the returned package for the actual renter was just a casualty. Or it could be an evolution of the above scam where the scammers don't bother with real addresses so there is no one to foot the bill.

This doesn't seem to be the same thing since in the question the package couldn't be delivered.

That is what I meant with casualty. I guess possibly it was just bad luck/timing, that the acutal renter ordered something that could not be delivered due to the wrong name tag. Or possibly, the scammer did not care to remove the name tag after their package was successfully received.
